# How to create from-white-to-color and from-color-to-black swatchs in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

Assume that I have an A color with value 0xff0f0f and two basic black and white colors. How can I create quickly a swatch consists of all medium colors between white and A(lighter) and between A and black(darker)?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** I'm practising some pixel-art shading, and I'd like to create a palette(or swatch) consists of limited colors that differ from saturation = 0 to saturation = 1. For example:

[image]

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you mean? Are you trying to write a plug-in that draws a gradient, or are you trying to actually generate color swatches that go into the color palette? Are you generating a file on disk, or doing this in the app while it's running? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You haven't answered the question. In what context are you trying to do this? Nobody can give you an answer if they don't know what you're writing. Is it an app, a plug-in, a library, something else? Is it running in Photoshop's address space? Stand-alone? Something else?

Comment: Oh man, I use in Photoshop workspace of course(I'm just a normal Photoshop user, no more).

Comment: @wanting252: As [outlined in the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions. Questions asking how to perform a task in Photoshop are off-topic. Please [read through the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get a better sense of what questions are a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this in Photoshop alone. If you are willing to pop into Illustrator, you can set up your swatches there and then export them as .ASE which can be loaded into PS.

Here is what I would do:

1. Open Illustrator and pick your main colors. Place them in a swatch folder.
2. Select the group and go to the Color Guide palette. Here you will see each of your picked colors going to both light and dark. Under the palatte dropdown menu you can find some useful settings, especially the Color Guide Options, where you can specify the number of steps.
3. Drag'n'drop the newly generated colors to your swathces palette. Once they are all in place, go to the Swatches palette dropdown menu and select **Save Swatch Library as ASE**. Save it somewhere logical. :)
4. Now go to Photoshop and open the swatches panel there. Select **Replace Swatches.** (Load Swatches appends them) and navigate to your ASE file.
5. Happy drawing.

PS: I couldn't upload images for clarification because I dont have enough Reputation. Yawn. Will update the answer when I can.